# Prolog Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated, R is [H|R1]

Tags: prolog, arguments, instantiation-error

I've read a few questions that are an identical question but different code, sadly another one is being posted.

I'm following my professors notes and modeling my insert statement identical to their factorial function as seen here.

```
factorial(0, 1).
factorial(N, F) :-  
   N > 0,
   N1 is N – 1,
   factorial(N1, F1),
   F is N * F1.
```

and my insert function is

```
insertPos(V, 0, [H|T], [V|[H|T]]).
insertPos(V, N, [H|T], R) :-
   N > 0, 
   N1 is N-1,
   insertPos(V, N1, T, R1),
   R is [H|R1].
```

The error is being thrown on `R` is `[H|R1]` which I was hoping to retrieve the `R1` from my `insertPos/4` and append the head onto it.

My query is:

```
?- insertPos(D, 1, [A,B,C], L).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `is/2` for unifying variable `R` with **`list`** `[H|R1]`, `is/2` is used for **arithmetic expression evaluation**.

Instead you can use **unification operator** `=/2` by writing:

```
R = [H|R1]
```

or by pattern matching on arguments:

```
insertPos(V, N, [H|T], [H|R1]) :-
   N > 0, 
   N1 is N-1,
   insertPos(V, N1, T, R1).
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using A B C  which are considerd as variables in prolog.

Comment: good observation but this is not responsible for the error, it will just produce a list of variables...